Cutting, Flattening, and Splicing Sparse Matricies in Python
I have a working code that takes two sparse matrices that uses arrays and for loops to cut, flatten, and splice them together into a new sparse matrix. I do not understand how I can cut, flatten, and splice them without doing it this way. Is there a native way with the scipy.sparse package to do this?
I have provided the code and a sample output.
Here is the working code:
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse as sps

# Construct 2 sparse matrices
rng = np.random.default_rng()
S_matrix_1 = sps.random(4,5,density=0.5,random_state=rng)
S_matrix_2 = sps.random(4,5,density=0.5,random_state=rng)


# Print the matrices
print('###########################################')

S_array_1 = S_matrix_1.toarray()
print('Sparse Matrix 1: ',S_array_1.shape)
print(S_array_1)

print('###########################################')

S_array_2 = S_matrix_2.toarray()
print('Sparse Matrix 2: ',S_array_2.shape)
print(S_array_2)

#Cut the matrices (trim edges off)
print('###########################################')

S_cut_1 = S_array_1[1:S_array_1.shape[0]-1,1:S_array_1.shape[1]-1]
print('Sparse Matrix 1 cut:', S_cut_1.shape)
print(S_cut_1)

print('###########################################')

S_cut_2 = S_array_2[1:S_array_2.shape[0]-1,1:S_array_2.shape[1]-1]
print('Sparse Matrix 2 cut:', S_cut_2.shape)
print(S_cut_2)

print('###########################################')

# Flatten matrices for stacking
S_vector_1 = S_cut_1.flatten()
S_vector_2 = S_cut_2.flatten()

col = []
data = []
row = []

# Gather Column data so that first matrix is in first row (0)
c = 0
for i in S_vector_1:
    if i != 0:
        data.append(i)
        col.append(c)
        row.append(0)
    c += 1

# Gather Column data so that second matrix is in second row (1)
c = 0
for i in S_vector_2:
    if i != 0:
        data.append(i)
        col.append(c)
        row.append(1)
    c += 1

print('Rows,Cols,Data for combined matrix of two flatted sparse matrices')
print(row,col,data)

# Construct combined sparse matrix, each row is a flattened sparse matrix
sparse_matrix = sps.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)),shape=(2,np.prod(S_cut_1.shape)))

print('###########################################')
print('combined sparse matrix, each row is a flattened sparse matrix')
print(sparse_matrix.toarray())

Here is a example output:
###########################################
Sparse Matrix 1:  (4, 5)
[[0.         0.         0.68617742 0.         0.        ]
 [0.76825482 0.3582357  0.         0.0248112  0.        ]
 [0.         0.33983419 0.         0.37449198 0.        ]
 [0.         0.13352901 0.79960432 0.79339374 0.48830805]]
###########################################
Sparse Matrix 2:  (4, 5)
[[0.         0.40899129 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.26789314 0.         0.950261   0.         0.21694661]
 [0.51039687 0.29567104 0.30580362 0.42007714 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.25469614 0.02599109 0.        ]]
###########################################
Sparse Matrix 1 cut: (2, 3)
[[0.3582357  0.         0.0248112 ]
 [0.33983419 0.         0.37449198]]
###########################################
Sparse Matrix 2 cut: (2, 3)
[[0.         0.950261   0.        ]
 [0.29567104 0.30580362 0.42007714]]
###########################################
Rows,Cols,Data for combined matrix of two flatted sparse matrices
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] [0, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5] [0.3582356963462584, 0.024811195277762876, 0.33983419283389527, 0.3744919847066006, 0.9502610017191933, 0.2956710439200694, 0.30580361813501, 0.420077135385148]
###########################################
combined sparse matrix, each row is a flattened sparse matrix
[[0.3582357  0.         0.0248112  0.33983419 0.         0.37449198]
 [0.         0.950261   0.         0.29567104 0.30580362 0.42007714]]


scipy.sparse can index (slice) CSR format matrices. It can use different methods, but most generally it constructs an 'extractor' array, and does matrix multiplication. COO format doesn't do indexing.  But COO format is used to make matrices from blocks (bmat, vstack, hstack).  For that it just makes a new set of data/row.col arrays from the source arrays.  CSR format can reshape.

In general operations like this are not as fast as the equivalents on dense numpy arrays.  Matrix multiplication on large very sparse matrices is this module's strongest feature.

@hpaulj I see so in order to cut of row and column edges I would need something like: A = S_matrix_1.tocsr()[1:S_matrix_1.shape[0]-1,:].tocsc()[:,1:S_matrix_1.shape[1]-1]

CSC has the same abilities as CSR.


Is there a native way with the scipy.sparse package to do this?

I don't think there's a single function that can do this - it's too specific. But you can write your own version of this, while staying within SciPy and NumPy vectorized operations, and without converting into dense format. This will be many orders of magnitude faster.
The general strategy is as follow:

Convert matrix into CSR, and do slicing to remove the first and last rows and columns
Calculate the value of the indices of the flattened data. Numpy has a function ravel_multi_index() which will do this for us.
Combine the two matrices into the same array and construct a matrix object.

Code:
def cut_flatten_stack(S1, S2):
    assert S1.shape == S2.shape
    S1, S2 = S1.tocsr(), S2.tocsr()
    S1 = S1[1:-1,1:-1]
    S2 = S2[1:-1,1:-1]
    S1, S2 = S1.tocoo(), S2.tocoo()
    num_rows = 2
    num_cols = np.prod(S1.shape)
    nnz = S1.nnz + S2.nnz
    # Use smaller dtype for columns if it fits
    col_dtype = np.int32 if num_cols < np.iinfo(np.int32).max else np.int64
    # Flatten indicies of both matrices to columns
    col = np.concatenate([
        np.ravel_multi_index((S1.row, S1.col), S1.shape),
        np.ravel_multi_index((S2.row, S2.col), S1.shape),
    ], dtype=col_dtype)
    # Create array of S1.nnz zeros, then S2.nnz ones
    row = np.zeros(nnz, dtype=np.int32)
    row[S1.nnz:] = 1
    data = np.concatenate([S1.data, S2.data])
    return sps.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(num_rows, num_cols))

Performance wise, this is about 20x faster than the initial version on a 1000x1000 array with 50% density.
I profiled this code, and found that it spends a lot of time converting between COO and CSR matrices. Since the slicing we're doing is fairly simple, I tried a version which directly manipulates the COO indices to accomplish the slicing.
This version is in general harder to understand, but it is about 4x faster than the previous version.
Code:
def cut_coo_matrix(matrix):
    """Remove first and last row and column of COO matrix"""
    assert matrix.getformat() == 'coo'
    assert matrix.shape[0] > 2 and matrix.shape[1] > 2
    mask = matrix.row != 0
    mask &= matrix.row != matrix.shape[0] - 1
    mask &= matrix.col != 0
    mask &= matrix.col != matrix.shape[1] - 1
    row = matrix.row[mask] - 1
    col = matrix.col[mask] - 1
    data = matrix.data[mask]
    new_rows = matrix.shape
    return data, row, col, (matrix.shape[0] - 2, matrix.shape[1] - 2)


def cut_flatten_stack2(S1, S2, format='csr'):
    assert S1.shape == S2.shape
    S1_data, S1_row, S1_col, S1_shape = cut_coo_matrix(S1)
    S2_data, S2_row, S2_col, _ = cut_coo_matrix(S2)
    num_rows = 2
    num_cols = np.prod(S1_shape)
    nnz = len(S1_data) + len(S2_data)
    # Use smaller datadtype for columns if it fits
    col_dtype = np.int32 if num_cols < np.iinfo(np.int32).max else np.int64
    # Flatten indicies of both matrices to columns
    col = np.concatenate([
        np.ravel_multi_index((S1_row, S1_col), S1_shape),
        np.ravel_multi_index((S2_row, S2_col), S1_shape),
    ], dtype=col_dtype)
    data = np.concatenate([S1_data, S2_data])
    if format == 'csr':
        # Create array to store pointers to beginning of each row
        indptr = np.array([0, len(S1_data), len(S1_data) + len(S2_data)])
        return sps.csr_matrix((data, col, indptr), shape=(num_rows, num_cols))
    elif format == 'coo':
        # Create array of S1.nnz zeros, then S2.nnz ones
        row = np.zeros(nnz, dtype=np.int32)
        row[len(S1_data):] = 1
        return sps.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(num_rows, num_cols))

This function also provides an option to emit the result in CSR or COO format. CSR is faster, because it avoids creating a large 'row' array, but if you have a future step which requires COO, then it is better to start in COO than to convert it later.

This will take me a while to understand but it looks beautiful. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Your matrices.  Let's make them csr right from the start, since we are going slice them.  tocsr is just as easy.
In [210]: rng = np.random.default_rng()
     ...: M1 = sparse.random(4,5, density=0.5, random_state=rng, format='csr')
     ...: M2 = sparse.random(4,5, density=0.5, random_state=rng, format='csr')
     ...: M1 = (M1*100).astype(int); M2 = (M2*100).astype(int)

And convert to int for a more compact display.
In [211]: M1
Out[211]: 
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [212]: M1.A
Out[212]: 
array([[ 0,  1, 81,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 71,  0, 24],
       [ 0, 37, 22,  0,  0],
       [61,  0, 63, 14, 14]])

In [213]: M2.A
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0, 39,  0,  0, 48],
       [25,  0, 18,  0,  6],
       [19,  0,  0,  0, 14],
       [12,  0, 77,  0, 48]])

CSR (and CSC) take indexing.  COO does not.  I commented that indexing is often done with matrix multiplication, using an 'extractor' matrix.  I don't know for sure if that's whats done here or not.  Slicing the rows could be easily done by playing with the indptr, etc.
In [214]: M1[1:-1,1:-1]
Out[214]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [215]: M11 = M1[1:-1,1:-1].reshape(1,-1); M11
Out[215]: 
<1x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

CSR also has a reshape method.  I didn't expect it to return a COO format, but for the following that's just as good.
In [216]: M21 = M2[1:-1,1:-1].reshape(1,-1)

Now it's easy to join them with sparse vstack:
In [217]: MM = sparse.vstack((M11,M21))

In [218]: MM
Out[218]: 
<2x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [219]: MM.A
Out[219]: 
array([[ 0, 71,  0, 37, 22,  0],
       [ 0, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)

In [220]: MM.data,MM.col,MM.row
Out[220]: 
(array([71, 37, 22, 18], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 3, 4, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1]))

vstack formats the task as sparse.bmat.  That in turn takes all the COO attributes, combines them in much the same way as you do, and returns a new COO matrix.
vstack and bmat code can be read via the documentation links.
reshape
Looking at the reshape code.  For CSR, the method converts itself to COO, and calls its reshape.  COO reshape constructs new col/row, uses the same data (depending on the copy parameter), and makes a new COO matrix.  So it favors generality over efficiency.
That fits the general philosphy of the scipy/sparse module.  Do the task(s) the format where it's easiest, and covert among formats as needed.
Keep in mind that the basic sparse formats, especially COO and CSR/C were developed many decades ago for use setting up and solving linear equations for finite difference and finite element methods.  And written in Fortran. Creating a Fortran stiffness matrix requires 3 or 4 levels of iteration.
